# How to get `pdftotext` to output text in a readable encoding?

Tags: text-processing, pdf

I converted a PDF file into a txt file using `pdftotext`. As an example, I have the sentence "This is the ﬁrst study on the functional relevance of", notice the f in "ﬁrst"; when I process this sentence through GATE I get "ﬁrst" distorted as "ï¬�rst". Also, in "proteins were isolated from episomally transfected HEK293EBNA cells and puriﬁed by afﬁnity chromatography on a", some words that contain a character looks like f but it not f is distorted as well "proteins were isolated from episomally transfected hek293ebna cells and puriï¬�ed by afï¬�nity chromatography on a".

How can I get `pdftotext` to output text in a readable encoding?

Answer (score 6):

Observe that, in the text you pasted, "fi" in "first" and "ffi" in
"affinity" are ligatures (multiple characters combined into a single
glyph). Presumably, `pdftotext` prints each of these ligatures as a
single character, which the tools you use to read the text do not support.

As a [Super User question](https://superuser.com/a/231637/418272) suggests, try this:

```
pdftotext -enc ASCII7 input.pdf output.txt
```

This should prevent `pdftotext` from printing ligatures verbatim, forcing it to expand them into ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was already converting pdfs to text in Python, I post-process the pdf text using a simple Python command:

```
# eﬃcient -> 
# efficient
import unicodedata
pdf_text = unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", pdf_text)
```